# Sprite kit animation frame per second less than 10 on Iphone simulator after installing Xcode 9. Is there any way to solve this

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Additional information

- Simple card game with more than **15 sprites** on screen at a time
- The game used to run in simulator on **xcode 8 ios 10 at 55 to 60 frames per second**
- **Installed xcode 9 today**. Simulator running ios 11. **Now the frames per second is around 5** when there are around 15 sprites
- **option on simulator for slow animations is off**.
- i am using this library https://github.com/evannnc/ActionQ which create a FIFO queue that will sequentially process any SKAction that is passed into it

Related Threads without solution

- [Xcode simulator extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378232/xcode-simulator-extremely-slow)
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83570

[image: Card Game nodes: 19 fps: 5.9]

Comment: Try installing and using iOS 10.3 simulator instead of iOS 11; see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ekscrypto Yes. Tried installing iOS 10.3 simulator now frame per second is 55. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in `OpenGLES.framework` in iOS 11/tvOS 11/watchOS 4 that causes them to skip loading the LLVM JIT and fall back to interpreting shaders. This has a severe performance impact on the Simulator since it is entirely software-rendered OpenGL (this includes CoreAnimation, SceneKit, etc).

As a temporary workaround you can copy `libCoreVMClient.dylib` from Beta 3 into the Xcode 9 GM and performance should be restored to what it was previously. This must be done for each platform runtime separately.

For iOS this is located at: `Xcode[-beta].app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib`

For tvOS this is located at: `Xcode[-beta].app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib`

For watchOS this is located at: `Xcode[-beta].app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion by @ekscrypto I installed iOS 10.3.1 simulator on Xcode 9.

Now the frames per second are around 55 and animations are fast or normal again.